# Don't enter gnuplot terminal

Tags: haskell, gnuplot

Using the [gnuplot](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gnuplot-0.5.1) module, after I plot a graph I get put into the `gnuplot` console. Is there a way to stop this happening? I never use it, and it's annoying to have to type `exit` after closing each graph, especially when I'm testing a sequence of plots.

For example:

```hs
module Main where
import Graphics.Gnuplot.Simple
main = do
    let xs = linearScale 100 (-10, 10) :: [Float]
    plotFunc [] xs sin
    plotFunc [] xs cos
```

I'm using Windows 7 x64 and the Haskell Platform 2013.2.0.0 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of the code you are running?

Comment: Also have a look at the easyplot package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/easyplot , which is another interface to gnuplot

Comment: @scravy Thanks, I'll see if that fits my needs.

Comment: @scravy Maybe it's a Windows issue - with easyplot, calling `plot Windows sin` creates a plot window which immediately closes. Calling `plot' [Interactive] Windows sin` opens the gnuplot console like before. I'll give it a go on a Mac when I get access to one with the platform installed.

Comment: Have you tried `persistent` (non-interactive)?  I know that's what you need on the CLI or C invocations at least.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
bind Close "exit gnuplot"
```

It should do the trick!

See here for bind details if you aren't familiar: [bind reference](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node65.html)